# PHP Command Line not running PHP files?

Tags: php

I'm currently firing PHP  from my Windows Command Prompt. Using:

```
C:\xampp\php>php -f c:\Uncrypt.php
```

Which outputs:

> ■< ? p h p   e c h o   " t t " ;   ? >

Which is strange, as according to the help document `php -h`. The switch of `-f` should:

> -f         Parse and execute .

But, this is not working. PHP is correctly installed & working when running through the browser, and:

```
C:\xampp\php>php -v
```

Spits out:

> PHP 5.6.3 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2014 17:18:08)
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Which means that the command line interface for PHP.exe atleast reaches this.

I have also added sufficient PATHs in the environment variables (both user & system).

After searching, the PATH variables seem to be the root cause, but running PATH does bring out my PHP directory, and there is file associations linked to notepad++ (could this be a possible error?)

---

As requested, here is the contents of this PHP file (screenshot with encoding to follow)

```
<?php echo "tt"; ?>
```

[image: Encoding & File Contents]

Comment: This character:  ■ at the beginning of your php file may be the problem, preventing parsing of the file.

Comment: you're outputting `<[space]?[space]p[space]etc...`. That's not a PHP tag. it's a bunch of space-separated characters that happen to kind of LOOK like a php tag. it's the difference between `MARC` and `M A R C`. one's my name, the other's a list of letters that make up my name. probably your file is in some goofy multi-byte text encoding that php can't parse properly.

Comment: Actually, could you upload the php file you are trying to execute, please? I copy and pasted the output you provide and it contains whitespace problems and all kinds of issues that are likely preventing php from parsing it.

Comment: Looks like being saved as UTF-16, not interpreting the

Comment: @MarcB UTF-8 Is the current files encoding, have tried ASNII also. Both are confirmed to be interpreted with PHP CLI

Comment: can't be utf-8. `<?php` is exactly representable in-utf8 without needing any extra bytes. `<?php` is identical in ascii and utf-8.

Comment: @MarcB Will destroy the file & try again

Comment: What happens when you simply run `php -r 'echo "tt";'` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try without the `-f`. I've had issues with that before.